# Plotting 2D Array of Values Using pcolor (python)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

So I'm plotting a grid of rain values in a certain area and I'm really getting stuck on the plotting step (or so I think). I've tried following a few of similar plotting examples but for some reason, they aren't getting me anywhere. Anyway here's my code:

```
# Necessary other stuff, RainArray is a 2D array of doubles
numpArray = np.array(RainArray)
nx, ny = np.shape(numpArray) #nx = 7933, ny =49

gridX = np.linspace(0,nx,nx)
gridY = np.linspace(0,ny,ny)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(gridX, gridY)

cs = plt.pcolor(X,Y,np.transpose(numpArray), vmin=abs(numpArray).min(), vmax=abs(numpArray).max())
cb = plt.colorbar(cs, orientation = 'vertical')
cb.set_label('mm/hr')
plt.xlim(0, nx)
plt.ylim(0,ny)
plt.show()
```

What I get out is a blue plot (everything is zero) with my colorbar scale from 0 to 10000. I just have no idea why this is happening, numpArray is mostly nonzero values so I can only conclude that I'm messing up with pcolor somehow. I followed all the guides I could find so any insight or better alternatives are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Other than the fact that you are strangely setting vmin/vmax to the min/max of the absolute value of your array but *not* plotting the absolute value, it looks okay. I'd fix that then see what it looks like.

Comment: I agree, that was a bit weird. I did change that but still having the same problem. Except I have a random uniform bar in the middle of my plot of a very high value. Still not sure what to make of any of it.